# Custom error messages based on object status

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

As for example I've got a model with several statuses.

```
class Task(models.Model):
    TO_DO = 'to_do'
    IN_PROGRESS = 'in_progress'
    DONE = 'done'
    TASK_STATUSES = (
        (TO_DO, _('To do')),
        ...
    )
    status = models.CharField(max_length=256, choices=TASK_STATUSES)
    creator = models.ForeignKey('user.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def is_to_do(self):
        return self.status == self.TO_DO

    def is_in_progress(self):
        return self.status == self.IN_PROGRESS

     def is_done(self):
        return self.status == self.DONE
```

And I've got endpoint where I want to perform an action on my task. Before this I want to check if this action is allowed to perform based on object status and other stuff. I may have several `if statements` like:

```
obj = get_object()
if object.is_in_progress() and object.creator.name = '...':
    raise NotAcceptable(detail=_('...'))
if ...
...
else: 
    obj.update_status()
```

Each exception may have it's own error message. I can store this messages on model but I still have a lot of `if` which only raise exception. So what is best way to perform such checks and keep my api views clean?

Comment: Use a *finite state machine*: https://github.com/viewflow/django-fsm It makes you think as the process in *transitions* between states.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It supports only Django 1.11

Comment: the idea is, use a finite state machine. You do not have to use the above linked library, but model states as classes, and add methods for the transitions. Whether you do that with `django-fsm` is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I like to share my idea which may be a solution of your problem.

```
status_message = None
error_type = None
try:
    # update/implement what you want
    print(1/0)
except Exception as ex:
    status_message = ex
    error_type = ex.__class__.__name__
    # get the status model by your exception
    model_obj = your_model.objects.get(error_type=error_type)
    if model_obj == None or model_obj.id == None:
        # if status model has not entry than created new one and than response.
        your_model.save(status_message=status_message, error_type=error_type)
        raise Response(your_model.__dict__) # you may serialize your response
    raise Response(model_obj.__dict__)
```

**Note: writing code in `except` blog is a bad practice.**